# Calling Java Interface functions : any other way possible?

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, awt

I want to have a JPanel respond to a MouseEvent, such as, mousePressed(), but not others.
I can do it via the following code added to the JPanel object:

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) { 
        //Some action here
      } 
    });
```

However, the anonymous function requires that I use final variables inside there. And my program specifications do not allow me to that.

I can also define the MouseEvents not as an inner class, but outside, but then I have to provide implementations for all the functions in the MouseListener interface, such as mouseClicked(), mouseEntered(), mouseExited(), etc.

Is there any other way of achieving what I'm trying to do, i.e. define the mousePressed() function without having to use final variables inside it, and also without having to define the other functions in the interface ?

Thanks a lot !

EDIT: I realize that the code I have provided runs without error because the inner class is creating an object of MouseAdapter which is an abstract class.

However, my question still remains : if I dont want to define all methods of the abstract class, and also not have to use inner classes, is there any way of doing so ?

Comment: *"define the mousePressed() function without having to use final variables inside it"* - Use instance fields instead of local variables

Comment: Just say `class MyListener extends MouseAdapter` in your "outside" class, and you only need to implement that one function that you want to override.

Comment: Read my above comment. Inner classes are not magic; your code above just defines an unnamed (anonymous) class that extends MouseAdapter. You can also extend MouseAdapter from a named class and have the same behavior where MouseAdapter already implements the abstract methods.

Comment: What specifically about final variables are you "not allowed" to use?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, if I do that, won't I have to provide definitions for the other methods in the MouseAdapter which is an abstract class ? I don't want my class to be abstract.

Comment: @chrylis I mean, the variables that I'm working with cannot be final, because they are supposed to be modified when a MouseEvent occurs.

Comment: @julianff Any reason not to call something like `OuterClass.this.setFoo(newValue)`?

Comment: @chrylis Yes, thats a nice solution ! Didn't occur to me. Thanks.

Comment: @julianff Technically you should still be able to say `OuterClass.this.foo = newValue` (`this` is final), but using the setter is generally preferred.

Comment: Cool ! @chrylis. Thanks again !

Comment: @julianff Have you tried? What happened? MouseAdapter has no abstract methods - otherwise you would need to implement each and every abstract method in your anonymous class as well - no difference between anonymous and named classes in that respect.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Hi! Yes, it does work that way. Sorry for the acknowledging late !

Answer (score 0):

One of the examples:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainClass extends JPanel {

  public MainClass() {

      addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
          public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) { 
            System.out.println(me); 
          } 
        }); 

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().add(new MainClass());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Also, you can use official tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/events/MouseEventDemoProject/src/events/MouseEventDemo.java).

Comment: +1, but the inner class MouseAdapter() still will allow modification of final variables only. The solution @chrylis provided is pretty neat.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!